# React-data-grid css is not loading correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, react-data-grid

Today we encoutered problem in production. For some reason our css is not loading correctly on the first render but after updating the path a couple of times it works just fine. As we debugged we undestood that the problem comes from the fact that a chunk is not loaded and css not being applied. Maybe it's because the css can't keep up with js loading times or something but this is really strange because it came out of nowhere with no changes from us. The video showcases problem, it's blured because of data privacy but you can still see the problem. In the start css is not loaded after that i open a order return back and the table renders just fine.

[Link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/103696749012467712/1168430831107313734/2023-10-30_08-05-20.mp4?ex=6551bd02&is=653f4802&hm=2168a9b9ece54c4308d11c92cc05e1363e37f334000777c3437e7976ee0cdb53&)

The library is react-data-grid and it's styles is not loading correctly here. We tried importing it in app, index but nothing happens.
the chunk itself is loaded in network tab but as we can guess it's not working in the render.
[image]